# Caret or Grid Cursor disappears when interacting with Ribbon Page

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have one main frame derived from `wxMDIParentFrame` and corresponding child frames derived from `wxMDIChildFrame.`

The main frame has ribbon Bar which is included as follows:

```
auto clientWindow = GetClientWindow();
bSizer1->Add(m_ribbonBar, 0, wxEXPAND);
bSizer1->Add(clientWindow, 1, wxEXPAND);
```

The child frames contain controls, such as one has `wxRichTextCtrl` and another has `wxGrid`.

For example the Rich Text Control is added to the child frame as follows:

```
m_OutputWindow = new wxRichTextCtrl( this, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 
        wxTE_AUTO_URL|wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER|wxTE_PROCESS_TAB|wxVSCROLL|wxHSCROLL|wxNO_BORDER|wxWANTS_CHARS );

auto bSizer1 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
bSizer1->Add( m_OutputWindow, 7, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5 );

SetSizer( bSizer1 );

Layout();
```

As shown in the image (for the rich text ctrl), the problem I am having is the caret at the wxRichTextCtrl or the grid cursor on wxGrid dissapears.

[image]

This happens when:

**1)** The user changes ribbon pages,

**2)** The user clicks on a control (such as wxButton or wxComboBox) that is on a ribbon panel. The problem does not happen with controls "native" to the RibbonBar,

**3)** The user clicks on an empty area (no controls at all) on the RibbonBar.

The downside is when this happens the user loses whereabouts of the caret's or the grid cursor's location.

When either of the 3 cases happens, the child frame is still active and my assumption is that the controls ( i.e. wxRichTextCtrl or wxGrid) on the child frame become inactive. Even if the user clicks on the child frame again (not directly on the control) the caret or the grid cursor is not shown. The user has to click on another child frame and then to the target frame to be
able to show the caret or grid cursor again.

How can I keep the caret or grid cursor visible when above-mentioned cases happen?

I am using wxWidgets 3.1.0 on Windows 10. Compiler is VS 2015.

Comment: I don't understand your windows hierarchy nor your sizers. A client window whose layout is controlled by a sizer?. Please post more code. and, if you can, a screenshot of the whole picture.

Comment: I edited the question and added more info.

Comment: I have a similar problem and still have not found a solution.

Comment: I have recently upgraded to latest wxWidgets and the same problem persists.

Comment: Finally came up with a fix: When working with controls that are not "native" to Ribbon, once the action is about to be completed with the control (the last line in other words), just give the focus back to the window using `SetFocus`.